# CSS3's :hover does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It does work in Chrome however.

I have a drop down that uses :hover on the .dropdownContainer to make the border blue from grey when hovered.

**The problem is** when I choose an option on the drop down  and the drop down items collapse (because i've already chosen an item), the drop down border still remains blue.

I suspect that this **is because the drop down items disappeared so technically I never mouse off'd the .dropdownContainer**

Here is the html with .dropdownContainer holding the entire drop down.

```
  <div class="dropdownContainer">
    <span class="down-arrow-blue dropdown-arrow-inverse-Grey"></span>
    <div id="content" class="selectedItem">Records Created</div>
    <div class="selectThis dropdownItems">
      <span id="buttonArrow" class="dropdown-arrow-Blue dropdown-arrow-inverse-Blue" ></span>
      <div class="dropdownItem" value="Records Created">Records Created</div>
      <div class="dropdownItem" value="Permits Issued">Permits Issued</div>
      <div class="dropdownItem" value="">Fees Collected</div>
      <div class="dropdownItem" value="">Inspections Done</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS below

```
.dropdownContainer {
 border: 3px solid grey;
}

.dropdownContainer:hover {
 border: 3px solid blue;
}

.selectDropdown {
  border: 3px solid blue !important;
}
```

You'll notice that I do not use the OPTION or SELECT tag. This is the javascript i used to replicate my own drop down. Adding and removing the class 'selectDropdown' also toggles the color.

```
    $('.dropdownItem').on('click', function() {
      $('.dropdownItem').removeClass('selectThis');
      $(this).addClass('selectThis');
    });
  $( '.dropdownItem' ).click(function() {
      var htmlString = $( this ).html();
      $(this).parent().siblings( '#content' ).text( htmlString );
      $('.dropdownItems').removeClass('animateDropdown');
       $('.dropdownContainer').removeClass('selectDropdown');
       $('.down-arrow-blue').removeClass('dropdown-arrow-inverse-Blue').addClass('dropdown-arrow-inverse-Grey');
  });    
    $('.selectedItem, .dropdownArrow').on( 'click', function() {
        $(this).siblings('.dropdownItems').toggleClass('animateDropdown');
        $(this).parent('.dropdownContainer').toggleClass('selectDropdown');
        $(this).siblings('.down-arrow-blue').toggleClass('dropdown-arrow-inverse-Blue').toggleClass('dropdown-arrow-inverse-Grey');
    });
    $('body').click(function(e)
    {
       $('.dropdownItems').removeClass('animateDropdown');
       $('.dropdownContainer').removeClass('selectDropdown');
       $('#datepicker-calendar').hide();
       $('.down-arrow-blue').removeClass('dropdown-arrow-inverse-Blue').addClass('dropdown-arrow-inverse-Grey');
    });
    $('.dropdownContainer').click(function(e)
    {
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: CSS3 `:hover` **does** work in Safari, but acts weirdly in Safari for iOS.

Comment: The `:hover` pseudo-class is a lot older than CSS3. Anyhow, are you sure that it's the `:hover` that is the problem, and not the `.selectDropdown` class?

Comment: I am sure. I've tested it without using !important in .selectDropdown and it doesn't make a difference. In Chrome, the drop down will never turn blue unless hovered over or on the initial click of the .dropdownContainer that opens the list of drop down items.

Comment: @DavidCorbin That doesn't answer my question or add much to the topic.   :hover does not work on ios at all because touch screens can't be hovered

Comment: `:hover` can work on iOS if you hold down on the element.